# Android Thread postDelayed is not working

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to make a Thread inside my code with a postDelayed to run it again one minute after.

When I run the application for the first time the it enters into the Thread but it doesn't run a minute after.
When I run the application for the first time, go to another screen and return, the thread is executed again and this time the postDelayed is working. 
Can somebody help me? I have been a week with this issue and I don't know what to try.

Code -->

Where the Thread is called the first time

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
        savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.map_title));

    if (null == handler) {
        handler = new Handler();
    }
    Log.d("MAPS**", "OnCreate View Inicialize stations thread");
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateStations);
    handler.post(updateStations);

    return mapView;
}
```

Where the thread is called changing the screen and going back to the thread screen

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (null != handler) {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateStations);
        handler.post(updateStations);


    } else {
        handler = new Handler();
    }
}
```

Thread code --> I know code is passing trought postDelayed because I have debug it and the log before is shown but why is not executing again the Thread a minute after???

```
public Runnable updateStations = new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                //******Some code***Log.d("---MAPS", " PostDelayed");
        thread.start();
        handler.postDelayed(updateStations, 60000);//define time how often the thread runs
    }
};
```

Comment: you can't use handler without loopper from thread.

Comment: Actually you can, the default constructor takes the Looper from the current thread  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler()

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have forgotten to call [`thread.start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) after creating your new thread.

Comment: I include a thread.start() in the Runnable as I edit the code and the behaviour is the same

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a thread on Runnable and you did not  start the thread. Use thread.start().

Comment: I assume the threaded code is not shown, but it may be needed to move work off the main thread, as that's where the runnable would be called.

Comment: It depends where you initialize the Handler. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: I include a thread.start() in the Runnable as I edit the code and the behaviour is the same